# Scalability of Using MySQL as a Key/Value Database

Tags: sql, mysql, performance, nosql, key-value-store

I am interested to know the performance impacts of using MySQL as a key-value database vs. say Redis/MongoDB/CouchDB.  I have used both Redis and CouchDB in the past so I'm very familiar with their use cases, and know that it's better to store key/value pairs in say NoSQL vs. MySQL.

But here's the situation:

- the bulk of our applications already have lots of MySQL tables
- We host everything on Heroku (which only has MongoDB and MySQL, and is basically 1-db-type per app)
- we don't want to be using multiple different databases in this case.

So basically, I'm looking for some info on the scalability of having a key/value table in MySQL.  Maybe at three different arbitrary tiers:

- 1000 writes per day
- 1000 writes per hour
- 1000 writes per second
- 1000 reads per hour
- 1000 reads per second

A practical example is in building something like [MixPanel's Real-time Web Analytics Tracker](http://mixpanel.com/report/85/events), which would require writing very often depending on traffic.

Wordpress and other popular software use this all the time: Post has "Meta" model which is just key/value, so you can add arbitrary properties to an object which can be searched over.

Another option is to store a serializable hash in a blob but that seems worse.

What is your take?

Comment: http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no doubt that using a NOSQL solution is going to be faster, since it is simpler.
NOSQL and Relational do not compete with each other, they are different tools that can solve different problems.
That being said for 1000 writes/day or per hour, MySQL will have no problem.
For 1000 per second you will need some fancy hardware to get there.  For the NOSQL solution you will probably still need some distributed file system.

It also depends on what you are storing.

Comment: without any tuning i got 4000 inserts per second to innodb on my celeron 1.8ghz

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that you'll have to run your own benchmark because it is only you that knows the following important aspects:

- the size of the data to be stored in this KV table
- the level of parallelism you want to achieve
- the number of existing queries reaching your MySQL instance

I'd also say that depending on the durability requirements for this data, you'll also want to test multiple engines: InnoDB, MyISAM.

While I do expect some NoSQL solutions to be faster, based on your constraints you may find out that MySQL will perform good enough for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

`SQL` databases are more and more used as a persistance layer, with computations and delivery cached in `Key-Value` repositories.

With this in mind, those guys have done quite a test here:

- InnoDB inserts 43,000 records per second AT ITS PEAK*;
- TokuDB inserts 34,000 records per second AT ITS PEAK*;
- This KV inserts 100 millions of records per second (2,000+ times more).

To answer your question, a `Key-Value` repository is more than likely to outdo `MySQL` by several orders of magnitude:

Processing `100,000,000` items:

```
kv_add()....time:....978.32 ms
kv_get().....time:....297.07 ms
kv_free()....time:........0.00 ms
```

OK, your test was `1,000` ops per second, but it can't hurt to be able to do `1,000` times more!

See [this](http://forum.gwan.com/index.php?p=/discussion/comment/897/#Comment_897) for further details (they also compare it with `Tokyo Cabinet`).

Comment: The link is dead and web archive also doesn't have a copy of it. Is there some alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the series of blog posts [here](http://karlssonondatabases.blogspot.com/) where the author runs tests comparing MongoDB and MySQL performance, and fights through the MySQL performance tuning mess. MongoDB was doing ~100K row reads per second, MySQL in c/s mode was doing 43K max, but with the embedded library he managed to get it up to 172K row reads per second.

It sounds a little complicated to get that high on a single node, so ymmv.

The writes/second question is a little harder, but this still might give you some ideas on configs to try.

Answer (score 0):

You should first implement it in the simplest way then compare that. Always test things. This means:

- Create a schema that's representative of your use case.
- Create queries representative of your use case.
- Create significant amounts of dummy data representive of your use case.
- In a variety of loops, including both random access and sequential, bench mark it.
- Ensure you use concurrency (run many processes randomly hammering the server with all kinds of queries representative of your use cases).

Once you have that, measure, test. There are different ways you can go about it. Some tests can be simple but might be less realistic. Measure throughput and latency.

Then try to optimise it.

MySQL has one particular limitation for KV which is the standard Engines with persistence use indexes optimised for range lookups, not for KV, which might introduce some overhead, though it's also difficult to have things such as hash work with persistent storage due to rehashing. Memory tables support a hash index.

Many people associate certain things with being slow such as SQL, RELATIONAL, JOINS, ACID, etc.

When using an ACID capable relational database, you don't have to necessarily use ACID or relations.

While joins have a bad reputation for being slow this is usually down to misconceptions about joins. Often people simply write bad queries. This is made more difficult as SQL is declarative, it can get things wrong, especially with JOINs where there are often multiple ways to perform the join. What people are actually getting out of NoSQL in this case is imperative. NoDeclaritive would be more accurate as that's the problem with SQL a lot of people are having. Quite often people simply lack indexes. That's not an argument in favour of joins but rather to illuminate where people can get it wrong on speed.

Traditional databases can be extremely fast if you do certain special things for that such as ignoring data integrity or handling it elsewhere. You don't have to wait for the harddrive to flush writes, you don't have to enforce relations, you don't have to enforce unique constraints, you don't have to use transactions but if you do replace safety with speed then you need to know what you're doing.

NoSQL solutions by comparison first and foremost tend to be designed to support various modes of scaling out of the box. The performance of an individual node might not be quite what you expect. NoSQL solutions also struggle for general use with many having quite unusual performance characteristics or limited feature sets.